# Fixed height overlapping sticky footer

Tags: html, css

I have gone through a lot of sticky-footer attempts but none of them seem to work with the latest browsers so I tried to build my own purely with CSS.

The code is below. Since I'm a novice web developer I wanted to ask if anyone can see any issues with the below code. It seems to be working with latest chrome, firefox and safari. Backwards compatibility is not important at this stage.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="page-content">*Page content*</div>
<div id="page-footer">*Footer content*</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#page-content {
    overflow: scroll;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    height: 100%
}

#page-footer {
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: the html id's should be surrounded by quotes ""

Comment: Why would you use `z-index:5` ?

Comment: @cclark413 Worth nothing that it's not strictly necessary to double-quote attributes according to the [syntax specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#attr-value-unquoted). However, attributes are typically double-quoted by convention, and there are less limitations on attribute values with quotes. More info is available [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes).

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have a Z-index:5 ?

If it is really overlapping 4 other layers, then yes I understand. But if it's not, take it out of there.

Although I would use a `<footer>.....</footer>` instead of `<div id="page-footer">*Footer content*</div>`

Besides that looks good.

Comment: How is it going to be on top of the content if I don't use z-index?

Comment: Let's say your content is a e.g. image and you want it to cover the full screen. Then yes, I would use a Z-index of 1 for the footer and a Z-index of 0 for the content. But this is only the case if you want the footer OVER the content. So not beneath it! 

If however you want the footer beneath your content, you don't need a Z-index for any of them. 

So if your footer covers the full width of your screen, you probably don't need a Z-index for the footer since it is sticking to your content on the bottom anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the ids with quotes, and add `display:block;` to your footer.

Comment: Why would you add `display:block;` to a `<div>`, it's already a block element?

Comment: A div wont acknowledge sizing unless it has content to fill it or display block turned on.